# Random music player with XNA

Tags: c#, random, xna

I have a little project of video game for my IT school and I have a problem : for this project I want to make a customized music player (the players will only have to add their music to a specific folder) and there is the problem : I know how to add one song to the game but if i want this player I'll need more than that.

Is there any way to "scan" the folder and add the musics to a List for example ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.IO;

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

Or

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.mp3");
```

for a specific extension. Then just randomly pick from the array.